# Connect \item and \minipage with arrows

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to connect an `\item` in beamer with `\minipage` using TikZ.

Here is a MWE

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item (some text)\\[0.3cm]

          \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
              \begin{flushleft}
                {some staff}\\
             \centering $\downarrow$ \\{text}
               \end{flushleft}  
           \end{minipage}
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                \begin{flushright}
                 {some staff}\\
                 \centering $\downarrow$ \\{text}
                 \end{flushright}   
            \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
```

What actually I want is an arrow to start from `\item` to the first `\minipage`, and another arrow from `\item` to the other `\minipage`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this exactly matches the request, but it is easy with `\tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{fromhere}](some text)\\[0.6cm]
\tikzmark{tohere}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
{some staff (with some other staff added just to show how the arrows are positioned with respect to the minipage)}\\
\centering $\downarrow$ \\{text}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\tikzmark{andhere}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
{some staff (with some other staff added just to show how the arrows are positioned with respect to the minipage)}\\
\centering $\downarrow$ \\{text}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[->] (pic cs:fromhere) |- (pic cs:tohere);
    \draw[->] (pic cs:fromhere) -- ($(pic cs:fromhere)-(0,4mm)$) -| ($(pic cs:andhere)-(1.75mm,0)$) -- (pic cs:andhere);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]